# How to avoid placing fields everytime a contract is generated with DocuSign Gen and DocuSign Envelope in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I have the following scenario that I need to put in place:
A user from SF must generate a contract with tables for a customer. As soon as the contract is generated, the user will handle the contract in a tablet to the customer, so he can sign it off in person.

To implement this I'm using DocuSign Gen to generate a template, because this particular template needs to have a table with multiple rows. So:

1. I declared all the `Salesforce Fields` I'm using on the contract .
2. I placed all the anchor texts on the MS Word file.
3. I declared all the `DocuSign Fields` (i.e. Signature, Name, Date Signed).
4. I also placed them all their anchor texts at the bottom of the MS Word file.
5. Finally, I selected a DocuSign Envelope (check the description below) template to streamline the signature delivery.

For the DocuSign Envelope, I simply created a template, but I didn't select any document, since that was going to be handle by the `DocuSign Gen template`. I defined the recipients (In Person Signer), and for the sending experience I selected the option `Send Now: Skips all controls and sends the envelope immediately.`

So, I was expecting that after clicking on the DocuSign Gen template button, the contract will be sent to the user so, he can handle the contract to the customer, **to sign it directly**.
Instead, after the contract is sent, and the user handled the control to the customer, they need to place **AGAIN** the `DocuSign Fields` (i.e. Signature, date, name) on the contract before signing it off.

How can I avoid that? I want neither the user nor the customer to place the fields again, since that's already defined on the template created on DocuSign Gen already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s absolutely possible to set up an eSignature Envelope Template Configuration that works with anchor-tag/autoplacement, either with or without a static document pre-uploaded into the template. There are default anchor fields we offer out of the box that are listed in this support article. But it’s also possible to create your own custom merge fields with defined anchor text with the {r} wildcard placeholder.
The trick is to also ensure your recipients use the standard role naming conventions of “Signer 1”, “Signer 2", etc.
Example:
If you have \s1\ on the document, then that will get assigned to the recipient you’ve defined with the role name of “Signer 1”.
\s2\ for “Signer 2.” etc.
If you create a custom field with the defined anchor text of something like `\ObjectName_FieldName_{r}\`
Then on the document you place the text as `\ObjectName_FieldName_1\`
That field would be assigned to “Signer 1”
`\ObjectName_FieldName_2\` would be assigned to “Signer 2" etc.

More information can be found here - https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=srl1586134368658&topicId=rvg1644270913133.html&_LANG=enus

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, linking an Envelope Template to a Gen Template renders the Gen Template useless. I can't find any clear documentation about how they are supposed to be used together.

This is what I did:

1. Created a Gen Template with a Word document that has all of my anchors.
2. I wanted the Recipients to be auto-populated, so I also created an Envelope Template (without a document) and linked it to the Gen Template.
3. I expected that when I clicked the Gen Template button, it would use my tagged template, auto-choose the recipients, and send. However, as you stated, you have to replace all of the fields. I have no idea why.
4. I tried @inbar's suggestion of using autoplacement. I created a new document with these tags and uploaded it to the Envelope Template. This works as expected, but it seems to render the Gen Template useless.

At this point, I think the best route is to not use a Gen Template and just use an Envelope Template with autoplacement. I wish the documentation was more clear about how to use these templates together.

Comment: thanks but not to use gen is not an option since I need to generate a contract with tables

Comment: @fingerprints Did you figure out a way to use Gen with an Envelope Template? It didn't look like Inbar's suggestion would make that possible.